# Angular : Can I access Object's property using interpolation binding for property name as index

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to bind value to a child component. The value comes from a property of an object. But for my work, the property name is a variable and I am looking for a solution to bind something like

```
[childInput]="ParentObject['{{PropertyKey}}']"
```

or even this

```
 [childInput]="{{getValue(propertyKey)}}"

and in parentcomponent,

getValue(propertyName:string): any {
        return this.ParentObject[propertyName];
    }
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Below is a brief explanation what I am trying to do.

My goal is to have a framework, when I pass it a Object (with data) and a collection of Form Items (that map to the Object) will display Form (to view/edit)

I am using the guidelines at [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) and I am able to display the empty Form based on a collection of Items that form the Form. I am stuck at displaying the filled Form (Detail).

eg collection of form Items

```
AddressForm [] = new TextboxItem(
                {
                    key: 'address1',
                    label: 'Address Line1',
                    required: true
                }
            ),
            new TextboxItem(
                {
                    key: 'address2',
                    label: 'Address Line 2'
                }
            ),
               new TextboxItem(
                {
                    key: 'city',
                    label: 'City',
                    required: true
                }
            ),
            new TextboxItem(
                {
                    key: 'state',
                    label: 'State',
                    required: true
                }
            ),
           new TextboxItem(
                {
                    key: 'zip',
                    label: 'Zip',
                    value: '',
                    required: true
                })];
```

The Data to view/Edit

```
SampleData[] = 
[{address1:"10 main st", address2:"", city:"New York", state:"New York", zip:"11017" },
 {address1:"20 Kirk ave", address2:"", city:"Albany", state:"New York", zip:"11700"},
 {address1:"1st ave", address2:"", city:"Queens", state:"New York", zip:"11145"}];
```

**The propertyName in sampleData is the value of "key" in TextBoxItem.**

Now when I bind the first item from sampleData, I want each property to bind to corresponding item of the form definition should display the data in the html control.

So I am looking at a solution  of something like binding the selected item from SampleData to the Form

*The Template of Detail Component:*

```
<TheForm [formObject]="theSelected"></TheForm>
```

and Form in turn should bind each of the property to the formItem. **This is the part I am stuck. My idea to get the value of property from the formObject like this *formObject['{{item.key}}']* needs your help.**

*a part of template of Form Component:*

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of formItems">
            <Item [item]="item" [itemValue]="formObject['{{item.key}}']"></Item>
 </div>
```

*and a part of template of Item Component:*

```
<input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="item.key"
               [id]="item.key" [(ngModel)]="itemValue">
```

I have trimmed the code just to give you the main idea of my issue.
If you need more info let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having real trouble understanding your three last snippets of code. Are these childcomponents, pseudocode or what?

Comment: The three are from templates of three components. the first and last can be considered actual code while the the middle one is a pseudo code to illustrate what I am getting to.

Comment: you should be using `ViewChildren` and `ngAfterViewInit()` to handle the dynamic components

Comment: @Aravind I am not manipulating DOM. I am trying to find a way to bind to a input using interpolation binding for propertyname. I changed my original post to highlight what I am really looking to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: didnt get you elaborate clearly

Comment: @Aravind please read the first part of my posting. I changed what I am looking for. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick [childInput]="getValue(propertyKey)" without the interpolation binding braces.